# How do I import a class that has a specific type in a format that uses "<" and ">" symbols?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, import

I'm trying to import the class AwsClientBuilder in library com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder into a .jsp file.

This is the documentation of the class: [Class AwsClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#build--)

Here is a screenshot of the pertinent part of the documentation:

[image: Class AwsClientBuilder<Subclass extends AwsClientBuilder,TypeToBuild>]

I am using Eclipse on Windows 10.

Here is a screenshot of my import statement:

[image: Import statement]

Here is a screenshot of the tooltip for the error:

[image: tooltip for error statement]

I don't know how to import a class that has that format, and I'm not sure what to search for on the internet.

Anyone can help me out with this? How do I import that class?

Comment: Nope, no longer required comments ;-) ... but it seems they are already gone ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These angle brackets tell you that this class is **generic**. This means when instantiating it, you have to provide actual classes.

Similar to:

```
List<String> someNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

I wholeheartedly recommend that you research this subject intensively prior using it. So start reading the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for example!

And yes, the other answer is correct: when *importing* it, the generics don't matter. You import it as any other java class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not and expert in .jsp though but if i am getting your question right, you are not able to import that particular class (AwsClientBuilder).
Just to be clear, the part of the class name in "<...>" is called generics. You do not usually have to include the generics of the class while importing it.

Try importing with just the class name(without generics)

```
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
```

or import the entire package if it makes sense

```
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.*;
```

A common similar example would be ArrayList<.E>, where to import this we just use the class name without the generics

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```